Show Tooltip Only When Hovering Over Image in Custom Angular AG-Grid Cell Renderer
I am using Angular and AG Grid to create a table with custom cell renderers. One of my columns contains both text and an image. I also have a custom tooltip component for this column. My goal is to show the tooltip only when I hover over the image, not when hovering over the text.
Here is what I have so far:
CustomCellRenderer Component (cell-renderer.component.ts):
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cell-renderer',
  template: `
    <div class="custom-cell" (mouseenter)="showTooltip()" (mouseleave)="hideTooltip()">
      <img src="{{params.data.imageUrl}}" alt="icon" class="custom-image" (mouseenter)="showTooltip()" (mouseleave)="hideTooltip()" />
      <span class="custom-text">{{params.value}}</span>
      <app-custom-tooltip *ngIf="tooltipVisible" [tooltipContent]="tooltipContent"></app-custom-tooltip>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .custom-cell {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
    }
    .custom-image {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .custom-text {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  `]
})
export class CellRendererComponent {
  params: any;
  tooltipVisible: boolean = false;
  tooltipContent: string = 'Tooltip Content';

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  showTooltip(): void {
    this.tooltipVisible = true;
  }

  hideTooltip(): void {
    this.tooltipVisible = false;
  }
}

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-tooltip',
  template: `
    <div class="custom-tooltip">{{ tooltipContent }}</div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .custom-tooltip {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      padding: 5px;
      z-index: 10;
    }
  `]
})
export class CustomTooltipComponent {
  @Input() tooltipContent: string;
}
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CellRendererComponent } from './cell-renderer.component';
import { CustomTooltipComponent } from './custom-tooltip.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<ag-grid-angular
               style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
               class="ag-theme-alpine"
               [rowData]="rowData"
               [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
               [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents">
             </ag-grid-angular>`,
  styles: [`
    :host ::ng-deep .custom-tooltip {
      display: none;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .ag-tooltip {
      display: block;
    }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  rowData = [
    { imageUrl: 'path/to/image.png', value: 'Some text', tooltipContent: 'Tooltip Content' }
  ];

  columnDefs = [
    { 
      field: 'value', 
      cellRenderer: 'customCellRenderer',
      tooltipComponent: 'customTooltip' 
    }
  ];

  frameworkComponents = {
    customCellRenderer: CellRendererComponent,
    customTooltip: CustomTooltipComponent
  };
}

However, the tooltip appears for both the image and text. I need the tooltip to show only when hovering over the image part of the cell, not the text. What changes do I need to make to achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated!
